# gps_waiting() returns 0 when fetching GPS data on Ubuntu14.04

Tags: ubuntu, gps

I am trying to fetch GPS data using a USB GPS device (UB-353+) on Ubuntu 14.04. Its name in the `\dev` directory is `ttyACM0`, by command `cat ttyACM0` I can see NMEA GPS data, as shown in the figure below.
[image]
Instead of parsing the NMEA data by myself, I want to get the latitude and longitude by the `gpsd` daemon, so I installed the `gpsd` and the `libgps-dev` using

```
sudo apt-get install gpsd`
sudo apt-get install libgps-dev
```

Afterwards, I use the following code to fetch GPS data:

```
/*compile command: gcc -o gps get_get.c -lm -lgps*/

#include <gps.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <math.h>

int main() {
int rc;
struct timeval tv;

struct gps_data_t gps_data;
if ((rc = gps_open("localhost", "2947", &gps_data)) == -1) {
    printf("code: %d, reason: %s\n", rc, gps_errstr(rc));
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
}
gps_stream(&gps_data, WATCH_ENABLE | WATCH_JSON, NULL);

while (1) {
    /* wait for 2 seconds to receive data */
    if (gps_waiting (&gps_data, 2000000)) {
        /* read data */
        if ((rc = gps_read(&gps_data)) == -1) {
            printf("error occured reading gps data. code: %d, reason: %s\n", rc, gps_errstr(rc));
        } else {
            /* Display data from the GPS receiver. */
            if ((gps_data.status == STATUS_FIX) && 
                (gps_data.fix.mode == MODE_2D || gps_data.fix.mode == MODE_3D) &&
                !isnan(gps_data.fix.latitude) && 
                !isnan(gps_data.fix.longitude)) {
                    //gettimeofday(&tv, NULL); EDIT: tv.tv_sec isn't actually the timestamp!
                    printf("latitude: %f, longitude: %f, speed: %f, timestamp: %ld\n", gps_data.fix.latitude, gps_data.fix.longitude, gps_data.fix.speed, gps_data.fix.time); //EDIT: Replaced tv.tv_sec with gps_data.fix.time
            } else {
                printf("no GPS data available\n");
            }
        }
    }

    sleep(3);
}

/* When you are done... */
gps_stream(&gps_data, WATCH_DISABLE, NULL);
gps_close (&gps_data);

return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

However, I found that this code frequently (not always) get stuck at `gps_waiting (&gps_data, 2000000)`, which means the function `gps_waiting()` returns 0. But I have no idea why this happens because the GPS device is working properly.

I have been stuck at this error for a couple of days, your help is very much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Not sure how familiar you are with C++, but would you like to try this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <ctime>
#include <sstream>

#include <libgpsmm.h>

int main(void)
{
  gpsmm gps_rec("localhost", DEFAULT_GPSD_PORT);

  if (gps_rec.stream(WATCH_ENABLE | WATCH_JSON) == NULL) {
    std::cerr << "No GPSD running.\n";
    return 1;
  }

  for (;;) {
    struct gps_data_t *newdata;

    if (!gps_rec.waiting(50000000)) continue;

    if ((newdata = gps_rec.read()) == NULL) {
      std::cerr << "Read error.\n";
      return 1;
    } else {
      while (((newdata = gps_rec.read()) == NULL) ||
             (newdata->fix.mode < 1)) {
        // Do nothing; don't want to output wrong initial time
      }
      timestamp_t ts   = newdata->fix.time;
      double latitude  = newdata->fix.latitude;
      double longitude = newdata->fix.longitude;

      // convert GPSD's timestamp_t into time_t
      time_t seconds;
      seconds = (time_t)ts;
      auto tm = *std::localtime(&seconds);

      std::ostringstream oss;
      oss << std::put_time(&tm, "%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S");
      auto time_str = oss.str();

      // set decimal precision
      std::cout.precision(6);
      std::cout.setf(std::ios::fixed, std::ios::floatfield);
      std::cout << time_str << "," <<
        latitude << "," <<
        longitude << '\n';
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

and compile:`g++ -Wall -std=c++14 -pedantic $(pkg-config --cflags --libs libgps) gpsd-example.cpp -o gpsd-example`

I use that code (a gist from [here](https://gist.github.com/elimpnick/8313815ac387e6757f751dc8960f03d7)) as my base for anything I do with gpsd and I have yet to have any weird issues.  Maybe we can narrow down if it's a compiler issue, gspd daemon issue or something else.

Comment: While waiting for an answer, I tried installing gpsd by its latest source code, and the problem was resolved. I will try your code later.